# If statements Ignored

Tags: android, if-statement

In my onPause I collect the question row and the visible button count. In onResume I then use those to restore where the user at. the code at the bottom is for the question and works fine. The problem is with the visible buttons. The If statements are ignored. Logcat shows me that the value of the retuned visible buttons (in this case) is 3 however it is ignored. I have tried different ways such as trying to convert "vis" to an integer before the if statement only to have numberformat exceptions. This current code is declaring values to strings for the if statement but to no avail. I hope someone can point me in the right direction please. Kind Regards Derek

```
    private void restoreVis ()  {       
    int i = 2;
    int j = 3;
    String strI = String.valueOf(i);
    String strJ = String.valueOf(j);        
    String file1 = "vis";
    try {
        BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                openFileInput(file1)));
        String inputString;
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();                
        while ((inputString = inputReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuffer.append(inputString + "\n");
        }
        String vis = stringBuffer.toString();
        Log.i(LOGTAG, vis + " visible buttons");

      if (vis.equals(strI)) {
          eliminateChooser();
          eliminateChooser();
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "equals 2");
    } else if (vis.equals(strJ)) {
          eliminateChooser();
          Log.i(LOGTAG, "equals 3");
    }else{
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "vis equals 4");
    }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     Log.i(LOGTAG," end of vis");               
}


    LogCat
     06-20 17:50:07.603: I/ON(18818): 3 visible buttons
      06-20 17:50:07.608: I/ON(18818): vis equals 4
      06-20 17:50:35.513: I/ON(18818): on Pause called
      06-20 17:50:35.513: I/ON(18818): 8 row Id
       06-20 17:50:35.513: I/System.out(18818): Visible children: 4

       private void restoreGameState()  {
    String file = "row";
    try {
        BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                openFileInput(file)));
        String inputString;
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();                
        while ((inputString = inputReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuffer.append(inputString + "\n");
        }
        String row = stringBuffer.toString();
        quest = datasource.findGameState(null, row);
        refreshDisplay();
        Log.i(LOGTAG, row + " value of rowId");


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Your file1 seems to be not correct. I think it has to be something like "vis.txt", there is no file ending

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the reason behind this behaviour is the snippet is that you are comparing `3\n` with `3` which are not equal. Remove `\n` from `stringBuffer.append(inputString + "\n");`.

Comment: Thank you very much my problem is now solved. the \n wasn't showing in the logcat or the file so I didn't realise is was appending it.

Comment: This happened to me before ;)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use something like :

```
else if (Integer.valueOf(vis).intValue() == j)
```

instead. Integer comparaison is easier.

Comment: Hi thank you for your response, I did as you said but come up with java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int. I had tried something similar previous but had the same error. Kind Regards, Derek